# Inserting two seperate fields into one record php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have created a planner using php and jquery on my application. I have a section, where the user inputs start date and start time, and another where they input the end date and end time. The fields are all seperate, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom">  <!-- datepicker plugin -->
<input type="text" name="time_from" id="timeFrom">  <!-- timepicker plugin -->

<input type="text" name="dateTo" id="dateTo">  <!-- datepicker plugin -->
<input type="text" name="time_to" id="timeTo">  <!-- timepicker plugin -->
```

What I want to know is once the user has inputted the above information, and submits the data to the database, instead of creating seperate columns in the table, is there anyway of inserting the `dateFrom` and `timeFrom` fields into one database column named `start_time` as a UNIX timestamp, and also the same for the `dateTo` & `timeTo` fields.

Can anyone give me any ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: Concatenation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the date and time using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get a UNIX timestamp before the insertion.

```
$dateFrom = "2013-05-13";
$timeFrom = "13:52";

$fromStamp = strtotime("$dateFrom $timeFrom");
```

> **Note:**
>
> Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y` format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (`YYYY-MM-DD`) dates or [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when possible.

Comment: You've been a bit faster. Yes just try to put your input data into this format "2013-05-13 00:01" and store it in a DateTime column

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (start_time, end_time)
VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$dateFrom $timeFrom'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$dateTo $timeTo'))
```

would do, assuming your $dateFrom is `yyyy-mm-dd`, and $timeFrom is `hh:mm:ss`. Of course, this would be subject to SQL injection attacks if you directly stuffed the form fields into the query, but this is just to show you one way you should do this.

Comment: My only hesitation with posting this type of solution was the possibility for injection.

Comment: use a parameterized query and php will take care of the problemf ro you. but you still shouldn't accept dates directly from a user, or someone'll try to pass in some degenerate `9999-99-99 99:99:99` or whatever.